# Performing Case Insensitive Queries with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I'm working in python using a mongo database. I'm using pymongo 3.6 to create a text index on multiple fields and to perform a case insensitive search but I'm having trouble.

I'm creating the text index using

```
text_index_name = db_collection.create_index([("name", TEXT),
                                              ("summary", TEXT)],
                                              name = 'text_search_index')
```

I'm then trying to perform the case insensitive search using:

```
name = "SomeTerm"
db_collection.find({"$text":{"$search":{
                     "$regex":re.compile(name, re.IGNORECASE)}},
                   })
```

This returns the following error:

> "$search" had the wrong type. Expected string, found object

I've tried to use collations by first creating a case insensitive text index

```
text_index_name = db.collection.create_index(
                           [("name", TEXT),("summary", TEXT)],
                           collation=Collation(
                                   locale="en",
                                   caseLevel=False,
                                   caseFirst="off",
                                   strength=2,
                                   numericOrdering=True,
                                   alternate="non-ignorable",
                                   maxVariable="space",
                                   backwards=True), 
                            name = 'text_search_index')
```

but I get the following:

> Index type 'text' does not support collation:
>
> { locale: "en", caseLevel: true, caseFirst: "off", strength: 5, 
>        numericOrdering: true, alternate: "non-ignorable", maxVariable: 
>        "space", normalization: false, backwards: true, version: "57.1" }

I've seen other posts where regex is used successfully but those were searching for a string in a single field like the kind below:

```
db_collection.find_one({"summary":re.compile("some_term", re.IGNORECASE)})
```

This also works for me but I am unable to use this with [$search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator with text search. However, text search is [case-insensitive](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-operator-case-sensitivity) by default so you can just do:

```
db_collection.find({"$text": {"$search": name}})
```